# Circle just after takoff EWR to EWY

Tags: takeoff

Any idea why this commercial flight (UA1822) would circle as seen in the picture after takeoff at Newark and heading to Key West Int.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a general answer, (or "idea"...) or specific details about this flight?  Because the general answer is probably sequencing delay by ATC.

Comment: That looks *very* much like entering a standard holding pattern... and then exiting the hold before completing one full loop. Possibly a hold over the Colts Neck VOR, but possibly not because the VOR is located basically between the two branches of the Swimming River Reservoir (the body of water immediately west of the text "Long Branch" on the map).

Comment: What was its altitude as it made those turns? Level? Descending? Climbing steadily?

Comment: velocity 322mph, elevation 11600 feet when the expected holding pattern begun and yes climbing steadily. When coming out of the pattern elevation was closing in on 17,000 feet and velocity 389mph.